# putting an image inside li tag is not expanding the li tag

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` tag inside a `li` tag, however, the `li` tag is not increasing it's height automatically to the height of the image

Example: http://jsbin.com/iroyev/

I want the `img` to come inside the `li` tag.  Meaning the background color will be `#F0F0F0` in this case.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating elements doesn't affect the size of their parent.

You can get around this by applying `overflow` to the `li` element:

```
ul#something li#someunit {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ubiquy/edit#preview

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are floating the image. Try adding a div just before the closing li tag the image with a clear property.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes. create a class in your css as such: `.clear{clear:both;}` then add the clear class to your div. `<div class="clear:"></div>`